# Canonical bundle definition

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, tangent-spaces, co-tangent-space

In the article 'More on Gauge Theory and Geometric landlands' by Edward Witten, I have read the term of a 'Canonical bundle'. I've looked that up and as far as I understand, the definition is :

$M$ smooth manifold, then $K= \bigwedge^n T^{*} M$ where $n$ is the dimension of $M$. Is that correct?

Comment: Did you try googling the term?

Comment: Yes of course. The definition I stated above is what I found, I just don't understand how it is used in the paper so I want to make sure that the definition I found is correct

Comment: I don't know where you found that definition, but that is not the common usage of the term. If $M$ is a complex manifold of dimension $n$, the canonical bundle of $M$ is the holomorphic line bundle $\bigwedge^n T^*M$.

Comment: I don't see the difference from what I stated..

Comment: You said $M$ is a smooth manifold, not a complex manifold.